# Google Map API V3 returns exception "Type Error" with Internet Explorer while executing geocoder.geocode

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Recently I have developed an Asp.net web application which uses the Google Map API V3 scripts for generating the Streetview, Panoramic view of passed address. The code and application works perfectly with Chrome, FireFox, Safari but the on Internet Explorer I am getting an exception

```
 "Type Error : Object doesn't support this property or method "

 while executing the API's ***geocoder.geocode*** function.
```

I have tried to run the same on IE 7 and 8 and both throws the same error.

---

### Code Snippet

```
geocoder.geocode({'address': addresstoshow}, function (results, status) {
            //alert(google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK);
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                mapStreetView.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                    map: mapStreetView,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,

                    title: results[0].geometry.location.description
                });
                marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', toggleBounce);


                panormacenter = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng());
                myOptionForPanorama = {
                    position: panormacenter,
                    pov: {
                        heading: 34,
                        pitch: 10,
                        zoom: 1
                    }
                };

                myOptionForPlace = {
                    location: panormacenter,
                    radius: '1000',
                    types: ['lodging']

                };
```

Comment: Are you sure you aren't getting errors in the javascript console in Chrome, Firefox and Safari?  What object is IE complaining about? (perhaps a jsfiddle that exhibits the problem, or a live link would help).

Comment: above function is giving me exception .. the same function works perfectly with firefox and chrome.. The exception is occuring as script try to execute the geocoder.geocode(..) function which is been detailed above..

Comment: The fact that it works "perfectly" in firefox and chrome, doesn't mean there are no javascript errors being reported.  Code very similar to that works for me in IE.  If it could be run it in a browser, it would be easier to tell what is going on.  The only suspicious thing is that your variables are not declared with "var", that will cause issues in IE if there are HTML elements with that name as an id.=, but you have't provided enough context to tell (i.e. your html).

Comment: hei thank you.. that really helped me to find the cause of that exception.. its not the geocode which is throwing the exception.. its a trim() function attached to 'var' contatinig the address causing the exception.. but here also ..the trim() function works well with firefox.

Comment: There is no trim function in your posted code.

Comment: geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var hdnAddressValue = document.getElementById('conrol containing address');
            if (hdnAddressValue != null) {
                address = hdnAddressValue.value;
                if (address.trim() != '') {
                    addresstoshow = address;
                }
                else {
                    addresstoshow = 'London, United Kingdom';
                }
            }
            geocoder.geocode({'address': addresstoshow}, function (results, status) {

Comment: @geocodezip  please find the code in the comment.. this code runs before calling the geocode function

Comment: Code in comments is pretty hard to read which makes it useless.  1. please edit the question to include the code. 2. You should change the title of the question and the tags as it now has nothing to do with the Google Maps API v3.

Comment: @geocodezip .. yes .. and the issue have been resolved.. the problem was with variable declaration..when i declared the var address globally and avoided the trim() function against it..its works..thank you..as your adivce helped to reverify the problem and helps me to resolve it..but can you give me the explanation why 'var' declared inside function was considered undefined ?

Comment: the issue have been resolved.. 

Firts of all.. the problem was not with the geocode.geocoder (its was my mistake)

 the problem was with variable declaration..when i declared the var address globally and avoided the trim() function which i used to check for empty string ..its works fine. 

thank you GeoCodeZip .. to help me analyse my mistake at the earliest..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with the posted code.

Comment: Right.. its not any google map api problem.. it was the issue regarding the scope of variable and the trim() function used against a var , on which Internet Explorer was throwing exception.